# Application terminating early because of GPUImageAverageColor block

Tags: objective-c

I'm receiving the following message in the console after my application quits early because it is terminating with an uncaught exception of type NSException.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 25 beyond bounds for empty array'

Here's my code:

```
NSMutableArray *redValues = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger redValuesLength = [redValues count];
float totalOne, diffForAverage;
int amount = 1;
__block int counter = 0;
NSInteger j;

GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageAverageColor *averageColor = [[GPUImageAverageColor alloc] init];
[averageColor setColorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat redComponent, CGFloat greenComponent, CGFloat blueComponent, CGFloat alphaComponent, CMTime frameTime)
 { 
     NSLog(@"%f", redComponent);
     [redValues addObject:@(redComponent * 255)];
 }];

[videoCamera addTarget:averageColor];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 27 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [videoCamera stopCameraCapture];
});

totalOne = [redValues[25] floatValue];
float average = totalOne / amount;

for (j = (counter + 25); j < (redValuesLength - 25); j++)
{
    diffForAverage = average - [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];

    if (diffForAverage > -1 && diffForAverage < 1)
    {
        totalOne += [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];
        amount++;
        [arrayOne addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(j - 25)]];
        counter++;
    }

    else
    {
        if (arrayOneLength >= 15)
        {
            break;
            counter++;
        }

        else
        {
            [arrayOne removeAllObjects];
            totalOne = [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the error message I'm receiving means that my redValues array is empty, but I'm trying to visit and manipulate later elements. How can I solve this problem? I know that my GPUImageAverageColorBlock is printing red values correctly, but it seems that these values aren't being pushed into the array like I'm intending.

Comment: Which line triggers the exception? Nothing here would indicate that anything is being accessed out of bounds. How do you know it's something in here and not elsewhere in your program?

Comment: `redValues` is a mutable array. You are only adding object to that array here . Please check the code where you are accessing it.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Edited to include the full program.

Comment: @KrishnaCA I've checked the code where I am accessing the array elements, but I can't find any discrepancies. I have updated my question with all of the code that is relevant.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have at least 26 values in `redValues`? Otherwise, accessing element at index 25 will throw this exception... Also, your loop condition is almost certainly wrong — `redValuesLength` is set only once, at the top of the function, before you've added any values to `redValues`. It's always going to be 0 (assuming `redValues` is empty at the beginning of the function), meaning you are always comparing `j < -25`, which is false, so your loop will never run. Instead, you should move `NSInteger redValuesCount = redValues.count;` to right before the loop.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm guaranteed to have at least 700 values. I made the change you suggested but the error still remains.

Comment: @KrishnaCA do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @fi12 I recommend placing a breakpoint at the beginning of this method and stepping through line by line until you find the one that throws the exception. The out of bounds access is happening at index 25, which means that some array definitely does not have that many elements.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Thanks for the help, I was able to find the problem. It seems my error was when I was actually adding the camera input into the redValues array. It turns out that statement isn't working properly, and thus all following statements involving elements of the redValues array cause the application to force quit.