# Code will never be executed warning

Tags: objective-c

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646178/application-terminating-early-because-of-gpuimageaveragecolor-block), I asked why my application was terminating early. It turns out I'm getting this warning on one of the lines below and that may help me solve my problem.

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray *redValues = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger redValuesLength = [redValues count];
float totalOne, diffForAverage;
int amount = 1;
__block int counter = 0;
NSInteger j;

GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageAverageColor *averageColor = [[GPUImageAverageColor alloc] init];
[averageColor setColorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat redComponent, CGFloat greenComponent, CGFloat blueComponent, CGFloat alphaComponent, CMTime frameTime)
 { 
     NSLog(@"%f", redComponent);
     [redValues addObject:@(redComponent * 255)];
 }];

[videoCamera addTarget:averageColor];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 27 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [videoCamera stopCameraCapture];
});

totalOne = [redValues[25] floatValue];
float average = totalOne / amount;

for (j = (counter + 25); j < (redValuesLength - 25); j++)
{
    diffForAverage = average - [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];

    if (diffForAverage > -1 && diffForAverage < 1)
    {
        totalOne += [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];
        amount++;
        [arrayOne addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(j - 25)]];
        counter++;
    }

    else
    {
        if (arrayOneLength >= 15)
        {
            break;
            counter++; // WARNING OCCURS HERE
        }

        else
        {
            [arrayOne removeAllObjects];
            totalOne = [redValues[j + 1] floatValue];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Why would the commented line above never be run? Is it a problem with my for loop, or my if statement, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a `break` command just before it. The `break` command will immediately take you out of the `for` loop, so the next line won't be executed.

Comment: Simple oversight on my part, thanks for your answer. I'll accept it once the time limit is over.